# Google Charts: How do I add a label to grouped column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a column chart produced with the "classic" corechart package.

But, I don't understand how to put the column values as labels on top of each bar. (eg. 8.50 on the very first).

Here's my code:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [
      "",
      "Hamburgers",
      "Pizzas",
      "Flutes",
      "Wraps"
    ],
    ["29-04-2017", 8.50, 8.2, 8.4, 5.5],
    ["13-05-2017", 8.60, 8.32, 8.53, 5.67],
    ["12-06-2017", 8.30, 8.72, 8.13, 5.37],
    ["23-08-2017", 8.50, 8.22, 8.43, 5.57]

  ]);
  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: ' ',
      animation: {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: "out",
        startup: true
      }
    },
    legend: {position:'top'},
    hAxis: { format: "date" },
    vAxis: {
      format: 'decimal',
      viewWindow:{
        max:10,
        min:0
      }
    },
    height: 400,
    bars: 'vertical',
    colors: ["#0F5470", "#8EA3A4", "#3EB8BC", "#98D4F2"]
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the *annotation* [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) to add labels to the bars

the *annotation* column should follow the *series* column in the data table

see following working snippet
here, a `DataView` is used to add *annotation* columns for each *series*...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [
      "",
      "Hamburgers",
      "Pizzas",
      "Flutes",
      "Wraps"
    ],
    ["29-04-2017", 8.50, 8.2, 8.4, 5.5],
    ["13-05-2017", 8.60, 8.32, 8.53, 5.67],
    ["12-06-2017", 8.30, 8.72, 8.13, 5.37],
    ["23-08-2017", 8.50, 8.22, 8.43, 5.57]
  ]);

  // build view
  var viewColumns = [0];
  $.each(new Array(data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1), function (index) {
    viewColumns.push(index + 1);
    viewColumns.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, index + 1);
      },
      role: 'annotation',
      type: 'string'
    });
  });
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: ' ',
      animation: {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: "out",
        startup: true
      }
    },
    legend: {position:'top'},
    hAxis: { format: "date" },
    vAxis: {
      format: 'decimal',
      viewWindow:{
        max:10,
        min:0
      }
    },
    height: 400,
    bars: 'vertical',
    colors: ["#0F5470", "#8EA3A4", "#3EB8BC", "#98D4F2"]
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);

  $(window).resize(function() {
    chart.draw(view, options);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

if you know the number of columns in the data table,
then you don't need to build them dynamically

the `setColumns` method takes an array,
each entry in the array can be a column index --> `0`
or an object, if using a calculated column...

```
{
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
  },
  role: 'annotation',
  type: 'string'
}
```

in this case, we need to include the columns from the data table,
and a calculated column for each annotation column

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [
      "",
      "Hamburgers",
      "Pizzas",
      "Flutes",
      "Wraps"
    ],
    ["29-04-2017", 8.50, 8.2, 8.4, 5.5],
    ["13-05-2017", 8.60, 8.32, 8.53, 5.67],
    ["12-06-2017", 8.30, 8.72, 8.13, 5.37],
    ["23-08-2017", 8.50, 8.22, 8.43, 5.57]
  ]);

  // build view
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([
    0,  // <-- x-axis column index
    1,  // <-- first y-axis column index
    {   // annotation column for first y-axis column
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);  // get formatted value from first y-axis column
      },
      role: 'annotation',
      type: 'string'
    },
    2,  // <-- second y-axis column index
    {   // annotation column for second y-axis column
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2);  // get formatted value from second y-axis column
      },
      role: 'annotation',
      type: 'string'
    },
    3,
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3);
      },
      role: 'annotation',
      type: 'string'
    },
    4,
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 4);
      },
      role: 'annotation',
      type: 'string'
    }
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: ' ',
      animation: {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: "out",
        startup: true
      }
    },
    legend: {position:'top'},
    hAxis: { format: "date" },
    vAxis: {
      format: 'decimal',
      viewWindow:{
        max:10,
        min:0
      }
    },
    height: 400,
    bars: 'vertical',
    colors: ["#0F5470", "#8EA3A4", "#3EB8BC", "#98D4F2"]
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);

  $(window).resize(function() {
    chart.draw(view, options);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**NOTE**

the reason you cannot build the columns dynamically using a regular `for` loop,
is because we're assigning the column index in an object

in this case, a reference is saved to `i`

```
{
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return dt.getFormattedValue(row, i);
  },
  role: 'annotation',
  type: 'string'
}
```

when the loop finishes and the columns are used in `setColumns`,
all of the columns reference `i`, which is the last value of the loop

to use the value of `i` during the loop, instead of a reference to a `i`

then the object being built has to be inside a closure, or function

which is why the `$.each` statement is used in the original answer

this creates a closure and the value of `index` is used,
rather than a reference to `index`

```
$.each(new Array(data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1), function (index) {  // <-- this creates the closure...
  viewColumns.push(index + 1);
  viewColumns.push({
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, index + 1);
    },
    role: 'annotation',
    type: 'string'
  });
});
```

Comment: Great, thnx @WhiteHat

Comment: BTW @WhiteHat, I am really not sure, whats going on in the //build view part of the code. I am not using jQuery and I tried to iterate without it, but can't get it to work. Could you please reproduce in plain Javascript?

Comment: i'll try to explain, see __EDIT__ and __NOTE__ above -- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/5090771) for more info...